# Javascript reset element.style

Tags: javascript, css, document

I have a script that adds form for user feedback to every page. It uses `document.createElement()` to construct a form (with inputs/textareas/etc.). Is there a way to reset all styles on such created elements to browser defaults (including hover/focus states), or to create elements that won't use any defined styles?

Comment: I'm assuming you have css that already is setting those "defaults" to something else? You should check out YUI. It has css default reset. But unless you give the elements specific id's or classes to apply the styling too, once you add the css file it will style all the elements on the page by what's in that file. Last css style applied wins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is “No.” There is no way to tell that some element be exempted from CSS code for the page. If you set `input { background: red }` (just a striking example) in your style sheet, there is no way to tell the browser behave as if the rule didn’t apply to a specific `input` element. You can of course override the setting, in many ways, like `#myForm input { background: white }`, but that means setting to a specific value, not to the browser default.

So try to modify your CSS rules so that they only cover what you want them to cover, typically using more specific selectors.

Alternatively, you might consider creating the form in a separate document embedded via `iframe` (since the separate document would “obey” only its own style sheets), but this would involve complications.